# Why my captcha doesn't display? And I can't click on the checkbox and the button?

Tags: checkbox, paypal, captcha

I'm using Chrome and I am trying to create a Payflow Gateway Account. I went to https://registration.paypal.com/ and followed all the steps to register. But when I was in step 3 (there are 4 steps in this step), it requires me to log in to the Paypal account. So I entered the email and the password, moreover, it requires me to enter the code in the `captcha`.

But I just saw a broken picture. I used the listen option but I can't hear anything! Can anyone explain to me why this happens, is it because my network is weak or because my browser is having a problem (or because of Paypal). I have also tried to enter a random code but when I was in the *Product Selection / Billing* step, I can't click on the checkbox and the button.

Is it because of that random code or because of another error? And if anyone can create for me an account, I will be grateful.

Comment: Try using a different browser, device, and internet connection for the signup.

Comment: I haven't tested on Firefox yet but I think that maybe not the problem because I am using the newest browser version. I have tested on another device but it even worse when the captcha has broken in step 2 (before my step) and I can't test another connection when I only have a Wifi. Can you try to signup an account and see does the problem appear on your computer?

Answer (score 1):

I tested the signup, and it worked for me. I was able to enter both captcha and proceed with signing in.

If you are signing up for a business product as serious as the Payflow Gateway, you should have the resources to do the signup from a different computer and internet connection. Even a friend's laptop at a coffee shop is likely to work around this issue you are experiencing.

---

As an aside, I do wonder why you are signing up for Payflow, which was a great payment gateway in its time -- but is now almost 20 years old. Do you have a specific need to integrate this?

There are better options available, like https://www.braintreepayments.com/country-selection

Or if jut want a simple credit card checkout, the black debit/credit card button of PayPal checkout: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client , might suffice

Comment: Yeah, it works for you but not me. You can see the captcha box? Why I can't! I have tested both on the computer, laptop, and phone. I use the same connection - my wifi. About why I am signing up for Payflow, this is the secret :) But it's very important to me :( I also want to ask that, in the *Product Selection / Billing* step, you used your official Paypal account ( used to login to `paypal.com`) or another Paypal account (business, ...)?

Comment: I logged in with a live PayPal account in good standing.  Since you tested on multiple devices, if there is no problem with your wifi/ISP, then perhaps the PayPal account you are trying to log in with is not in good standing or not usable for this for some reason.

Comment: So, you can maybe try singing up for a new PayPal business account on www.paypal.com .  My first recommendation is to test from a completely different computer and ISP, just to rule that out for sure, since captcha problems are usually related to that.

Comment: I will try! Thank you for that!

Comment: Hi, it's so funny that after entering some random information as fast as possible to can give you the picture of my error, I just realized that it's worked! But I have entered random information which not the thing I want to do so I reload the page and enter the information I want but again, the error appears T_T! Can you please please to register for me an account! I totally very need right now. You can use Tempmail for that.